# Caused by error in `vapply()`: ! values must be length 1, but FUN(X[[2]]) result is length 2684

Tags: r

I am working with baseball data in R, and I want to use mutate() to get a team's opponent's win record on the date that team played them. I wrote a function to do that:

```
library(baseballr)
library(tidyverse)

    win_percent <- function(Tm, DateFull) {
      df <- rbind(mlb_standings(season = 2022, date = DateFull, league_id = 104),mlb_standings(season = 2022, date = DateFull, league_id = 103))
      
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Baltimore Orioles"] <- "BAL"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Boston Red Sox"] <- "BOS"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Chicago White Sox"] <- "CHW"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Cleveland Guardians"] <- "CLE"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Detroit Tigers"] <- "DET"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Houston Astros"] <- "HOU"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Kansas City Royals"] <- "KCR"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Los Angeles Angels"] <- "LAA"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Minnesota Twins"] <- "MIN"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "New York Yankees"] <- "NYY"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Oakland Athletics"] <- "OAK"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Seattle Mariners"] <- "SEA"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Tampa Bay Rays"] <- "TBR"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Texas Rangers"] <- "TEX"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Toronto Blue Jays"] <- "TOR"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Arizona Diamondbacks"] <- "ARI"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Atlanta Braves"] <- "ATL"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Chicago Cubs"] <- "CHC"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Cincinnati Reds"] <- "CIN"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Colorado Rockies"] <- "COL"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Los Angeles Dodgers"] <- "LAD"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Miami Marlins"] <- "MIA"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Milwaukee Brewers"] <- "MIL"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "New York Mets"] <- "NYM"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Philadelphia Phillies"] <- "PHI"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Pittsburgh Pirates"] <- "PIT"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "San Diego Padres"] <- "SDP"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "San Francisco Giants"] <- "SFG"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "St. Louis Cardinals"] <- "STL"
      df$team_records_team_name[df$team_records_team_name == "Washington Nationals"] <- "WSN"
      
      df <- df %>%
        filter(team_records_team_name == Tm) %>%
        select(team_records_winning_percentage)
      value <- as.numeric(df$team_records_winning_percentage)
      
      print(value)
    }
```

Here is a sample data frame that the relevant variables for the function to work

```
   Tm    DateFull  
   <fct> <date>    
 1 OAK   2022-04-08
 2 OAK   2022-04-09
 3 OAK   2022-04-10
 4 OAK   2022-04-11
 5 OAK   2022-04-12
 6 OAK   2022-04-13
 7 OAK   2022-04-14
 8 OAK   2022-04-15
 9 OAK   2022-04-16
10 OAK   2022-04-17
```

This is the code I then try to run using this data frame:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    win_perc = win_percent(Tm, DateFull)
  )
```

After which I get this error message (for reference there are 2684 rows in the actual data frame):

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `win_perc = win_percent(Tm, DateFull)`.
Caused by error in `vapply()`:
! values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[2]]) result is length 2684
```

Any guidance on how I should go about fixing this would be appreciated.

Comment: your code will not work. you have `Tm` as a vector passed into the fnction yet in the function `Tm` is a single value. Consider using `str_replace_all/recode/recode_factor/fct_recode` to simplify your your task

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: The expected output is a number, such as 0.500, to represent the percent of games a team has won on a given date. The function works when I use it on its own, but it won't work inside of the mutate() function.